# Grep pattern to output substring if line contains string

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I'd like Grep (or awk or sed) to output word2 on a new line if word3 is 'nn1'.  Each line in my tab delimited source text file is

```
<number> <word1> <word2> <word3> <lots of junk>
```

Or do I need to do this in two passes - one to isolate the line, and one to pull out word2?

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: Thanks for the edit - that was very confusing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk '$4 == "nn1"{print $3}' file
```

**Note:** For a tab delimited file as well above awk command will work since space or tab are default delimiters.

However **if you want fields to be split only on tabs and NOT on spaces** then use:

```
awk -F'\t' '$4 == "nn1"{print $3}' file
```

Comment: may be useful to say `-F"\t"` since it apparently is a tab-separated file

Comment: @MattParkins - of course it did. THINK about why that would be the case given the sample input you've posted and why it would not work for other input cases that can be present in a tab-separated file (hint - what if `<word1>` was `uh oh`). Getting the output you expect from a small input sample you posted is just the starting point to identifying a solution.

Comment: @EdMorton Settled down.  The only thing I did wrong was not be explicit enough about "word" meaning a single word.

Answer (score 5):

Awk is the tool for the job:

```
awk '$4 == "nn1" { print $3 }' file
```

If the fourth column is `nn1`, print the third.

By default, awk splits the line on any number of white space characters (tabs or spaces). As you have said "word1", "word2", etc. I guess that there are no spaces within each field, so the default behaviour should be OK. However, if you want to be explicit, you can specify the field separator yourself:

```
awk -F'\t' '$4 == "nn1" { print $3 }' file
```

Comment: may be useful to say `-F"\t"` since it apparently is a tab-separated file